# Video Editor: Modify various strips of a subtitle text

Tags: video-sequence-editor

I try to modify various strips of a subtitle text in video editor but I don't find how to do it.
For exemple If I want to change the color of one line of text it is possible if I select one line and change in Strip/Style/Color. But if I select various lines and change the color in the color box it change only the color of the selected line with white selection.

[image]

Comment: That’s something for scripting. There might be an add-on or special operator for it somewhere, but it can be scripted without too much trouble.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The white outline means that it is the active strip. The properties on the active strip is displayed in the sidebar.
The orange outline means selected strips.

If you want to copy the properties of the active strip to the selected strips, you'll need to press Alt while changing the values. Or right-click on the property and select Copy to Selected:
[image]

Unfortunately, this doesn't work for changing the font.

So, I added copying all visual properties of the active Text strip to the selected Text strips(including the font) to my Subtitle Import add-on.
[image]
Get it here: https://github.com/tin2tin/import_subtitles

Comment: I pasted your script in text editor and runned it. But the "copy properties to selected" option do not appear.

Comment: The "import subtitle" option well appear on the other hand. I use blender 2.93.8

Comment: Did you have both an active strip and selected strips selected(white+orange outlines)?

Comment: Yes and it is still the same. The button "copy property to selected" is not here

Comment: Since it is working fine here on 3.2, there is not much I can say other than try to update Blender.

Comment: I tried with blender 3.1.2 and it work. Thank you !